# Measuring microphone input voice level in dB-SPL

Tags: c#, audio, microphone

I posted a question to measure speakers voice level in dB and got answer that it is not possible. I want to develop an application that measures dB-SPL of voices. If not possible with speaker is it possible with microphone to do so? Please guide me in this issue!

Comment: You should explain your situation a bit more. It may or may not be possible because the mike and soundcard and so on need to be calibrated.

Comment: The decibel scale is a logarithmic power ratio relative to a reference point. For sound pressure measurements, that reference is 20uPa.

Comment: @Bjorn Roche Yes this for sure calibration is mandatory but for instance, we assume the system is calibrated.

Comment: @Marko Thats true! I believe this is the formula if I am not wrong.                                                            20Log10(Pressure of measureing sound/20uPa)

Comment: You are choosing to measure some a property that has a known relationship with pressure.  In the case of a microphone, V varies proportionally with Pressure (more or less), and V*V is proportional to signal power.  This makes the equation: `SPL = 20log10(Vsignal / VTwentyMicroPa)`

Comment: You may want to use this as a starting point (it does not answer your question, as it is calibrated to dBFS and you probably want RMS rather than peak): http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013/07/peak-meters-dbfs-and-headroom.html

Comment: @Marko Thanks for your comments. Please if you can further let me know about VTwentMicroPascal. What is its value? beacause it might be a constant value, I believe!

Comment: @MuhammadMansoor Calibrating a scale 101: VTwentyMicroPascal is a known calibration point that is (you hope) constant for your particular system. You will need to measure it (or extrapolate it using some other known measurement point).